# How to get more detail for Black Formatter errors?

Tags: python, git, gitlab

I use black formatter to check my code. By running this code:

`python3 -m black --check --preview --line-length=120 .`

I get this error:

```
would reformat /Users/a/model.py
would reformat /Users/a/test.py

Oh no!   
2 files would be reformatted, 193 files would be left unchanged.
```

but I don't know how should I change those two files to make the black formatter run without error.

I have already changed the files to not have any line longer than 120 characters.

Comment: That's how black is supposed to work. See the [--check](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#check) docs for details. If you want to actually reformat the files, remove the `--check` option. black is not meant to lint your files, there are separate tools for this purpose like [pycodestyle](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/).